# ifstream variable loop prints nothing

Tags: c++, ifstream, cout

I'm having trouble understanding why my program has no output.
Can someone please point out the rule I'm overlooking? As you can see I read a file in a class, and access the same classes print function through a subclass inherited publicly.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class mainClass
{
public:
    void print();
    void read();
    std::ifstream dataFile;

protected:
    double first, second;
    std::string mainString;
    bool truth;
};

void mainClass::read()
{
    dataFile.open("data.txt");  
}

void mainClass::print()
{
    while (dataFile >> mainString >> first >> second >> truth)
    {
        std::cout << mainString << first << second << truth;
    }
}

int main()
{
    mainClass instance;
    instance.read();
    instance.print();
    return 0;
}
```

data.txt:

```
Pie 3.14515 69 true
Apple 4.234 42 true
Potato 5 4.532 false
Carrot 55 1.2204 true
Corn 7.53221 12 false
```

Comment: Can you share the content of `data.txt`?

Comment: I edited the question and added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read boolean values from text like this, you must use the I/O manipulator `std::boolalpha`.  *e.g.*:

```
dataFile >> std::boolalpha;
while (dataFile >> mainString >> first >> second >> truth)
{
    std::cout << mainString << first << second << std::boolalpha << truth;
}
```

Reference for `std::boolalpha`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha

Answer (score 1):

Your reading operator `dataFile >> mainString >> first >> second >> truth` always fail because it cannot read the boolean values 'true/false'. You should use the `std::boolalpha` modifier if you want to read boolean values as text

```
 dataFile >> mainString >> first >> second >> std::boolalpha >> truth;
```